# Calling a Perl module from another Perl program

Tags: perl, module

I am analyzing an existing infrastructure of static analysis tool. I see there is a perl module/file called `static_analysis.pm` and also a directory with the name `static_analysis`. And I see other scripts such as `run_sa` having the statement `use static_analysis`. I am not able to understand whether `use static_analysis` is calling the perl module/file or the directory.

Comment: Did you try `use static_analysis;`? Does it not work for some reason? If so, why? Do you get an error message?

Comment: This is all rather unclear. `static_analysis.pm` seems to be a module, not a script. You load a module in a program with the `use` statement. Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: The problem I am actually having is that I am analyzing an existing infrastructure of static analysis tool. I see there is a perl script 'file' called 'static_analysis.pm' and also  a 'directory' with the name 'static_analysis' . And I see other scripts such as 'run_sa' having the command 'use static_analysis'. I am not able to understand by 'use static_analysis' are they calling the perl script file or the directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, [`use Module`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) *imports some semantics into the current package from the named module, generally by aliasing certain subroutine or variable names into your package*.

Thus, the statement `use static_analysis` imports from the **file** (module) `static_analysis.pm`, not from the directory `static_analysis`.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: To add: the directory may still be used by other `use` statements, as for example `use static_analysis::foo;` would load the file `static_analysis/foo.pm` relative to `@INC`. This is only an organizational relation: the two packages have nothing to do with each other intrinsically.